# How to generate closing nodes in a file that is not a valid xml file?

Tags: c#

How do I add closing nodes of a given node (`<sec>`) in certain positions in a text file which is not a valid xml file. I know its a bit confusing but here is [sample input text](https://codeshare.io/5emeYr) and here is its [desired output](https://codeshare.io/add9DR)

Basically the program should generate `</sec>` node before the next `<sec>` node and how many `</sec>`'s will it add to the required place depend on the attribute `id` of the node `<sec>` using the digits separated by a `.` as follows:

if the next `<sec>` node after say, `<sec id="4.5">` is `<sec id="5">` then 2 `</sec>` should be added before `<sec id="5">`

if the next `<sec>` node after say, `<sec id="3.2.1.2">` is `<sec id="3.4">` then 3 `</sec>` nodes should be added before `<sec id="3.4">`

I cannot use any xml parsing methods to do this obviously, what other way can this be done....I'm clueless at this point...
Can anyone help?
sample input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
<sec id="sec1">
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>Tuberculosis is associated with high mortality rate although according to the clinical trials that have been documented</p>
<sec id="sec1.2">
<title>Related Work</title>
<p>The main contributions in this study are:
<list list-type="ordered">
<list-item><label>I.</label><p>Introducing SURF features descriptors for TB detection which for our knowledge has not been used in this problem before.</p></list-item>
<list-item><label>II.</label><p>Providing an extensive study of the effect of grid size on the accuracy of the SURF.</p></list-item>
</list></p>
</sec>
<sec id="sec1.3">
<title>Dataset</title>
<p>The dataset used in this work is a standard computerized images database for tuberculosis gathered and organized by National Library of Medicine in collaboration with the Department of Health and Human Services, Montgomery County, Maryland; USA <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref15">[15]</xref>. The set contains 138 x-rays, 80 for normal cases and 58 with TB infections. The images are annotated with clinical readings comes in text notes with the database describing age, gender, and diagnoses. The images comes in 12 bits gray levels, PNG format, and size of 4020*4892. The set contains x-ray images information gathered under Montgomery County&#x0027;s Tuberculosis screening program.</p>
<sec id="sec1.3.5">
<sec id="sec1.3.5.2">
<title>Methodologies</title>
<sec id="sec2">
<p>The majority of TB and death cases are in developing countries.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5">
<p>The disordered physiological manifestations associated with TB is diverse and leads to a complex pathological changes in the organs like the lungs.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5.3">
<sec id="sec2.5.3.1">
<p>The complexity and diversity in the pulmonary manifestations are reported to be caused by age.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5.3.1.1">
</sec>
</sec>
</body>
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
<sec id="sec1">
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>Tuberculosis is associated with high mortality rate although according to the clinical trials that have been documented</p>
<sec id="sec1.2">
<title>Related Work</title>
<p>The main contributions in this study are:
<list list-type="ordered">
<list-item><label>I.</label><p>Introducing SURF features descriptors for TB detection which for our knowledge has not been used in this problem before.</p></list-item>
<list-item><label>II.</label><p>Providing an extensive study of the effect of grid size on the accuracy of the SURF.</p></list-item>
</list></p>
</sec>
<sec id="sec1.3">
<title>Dataset</title>
<p>The dataset used in this work is a standard computerized images database for tuberculosis gathered and organized by National Library of Medicine in collaboration with the Department of Health and Human Services, Montgomery County, Maryland; USA <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref15">[15]</xref>. The set contains 138 x-rays, 80 for normal cases and 58 with TB infections. The images are annotated with clinical readings comes in text notes with the database describing age, gender, and diagnoses. The images comes in 12 bits gray levels, PNG format, and size of 4020*4892. The set contains x-ray images information gathered under Montgomery County&#x0027;s Tuberculosis screening program.</p>
<sec id="sec1.3.5">
<sec id="sec1.3.5.2">
<title>Methodologies</title>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
<sec id="sec2">
<p>The majority of TB and death cases are in developing countries.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5">
<p>The disordered physiological manifestations associated with TB is diverse and leads to a complex pathological changes in the organs like the lungs.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5.3">
<sec id="sec2.5.3.1">
<p>The complexity and diversity in the pulmonary manifestations are reported to be caused by age.</p>
<sec id="sec2.5.3.1.1">
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm afraid, you need to build your own 'parser' or 'fixer'. Some years ago I had to do something similar. In my case it was always incomplete XML *(not finished XML)*, therefore all I did was check lines backward for missing close node(s). Since it was in work, I can not check the code now. But I'm not so sure if this would help in your case. The check was probably see if there is closing root node and add if there was not. I'm not sure if the check was able to add another not closed child nodes.

Comment: In your sample output - 3 </sec> nodes were also added before closing </body> tag, which seems not described in your algorithm.

Comment: @Evk because the number of INTEGER values in the attribute `id` of the node `sec` is 5 and there are no other `sec` nodes left after that, that is why a total of 5 `</sec>` added before `</body>`....also, say there is a node `<sec id="sec3.5.3.3">` and the next `sec` after that is `<sec id="sec3.7">` then 3 `</sec>` should be added before `<sec id="sec3.7">` i.e. no. of INT values in the `<sec id="sec3.5.3.3">` is 4 and no. of INT values in the `<sec id="sec3.7">` is 2, so the no. of `</sec>` that needs to be added before `<sec id="sec3.7">` is =4-2+`1`=3....

Comment: Also...if the next `sec` node after say, `<sec id="sec2.2">` is `<sec id="sec2.2.2">` then no </sec> should be added before `<sec id="sec2.2.2">` as no. of INT values in the current `sec` node 3 which is higher than the previous `sec` nodes INT value count 2... so 2-3 is negative, it must be > or equal to 0  for any </sec> to be added before it

Comment: Quite simply, if the parsing rules are non-`XML` compliant, then you're going to need to write your own parser.

Comment: your sample input and output links are not working. It will be good if you share texts.

Comment: @GaurangDave I've added the sample texts in my question post

Comment: You could try to use a parser like https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/XmlParser which can parse defect documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this task, I defined one additional method, which will return how many closing tags `</sec>` should be inserted based on the difference in IDs:

```
public static int HowManyClosingTags(string startTagId, string endTagId)
{
   // if IDs are the same, then we don't need any closing tags
   if(startTagId == endTagId )
      return 0;
   // if following ID is subsection of previous tag section, then we don't need any closing tags
   if (endTagId.IndexOf(startTagId) == 0)
      return 0;

   int i = 0;
   while (startTagId[i] == endTagId[i])
      i++;

   return startTagId.Substring(i).Count(ch => ch == '.') + 1;
}
```

I work with string, as it's invalid XML and can't be loaded as one (`XmlDocument.Load()` method throws exception in case of invalid XML). So I'm doing basic operations on strings (which I hope will be understandable in code, also I included as many comments as I could think of to make it clear). Below is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string invalidXml = "your invalid XML";
    int closeTagPos = -1;
    int openTagPos = -1;
    string openTagId = "";
    string closeTagId = "";
    int howManyClosingTagsAlready;
    int lastPos;
    int howManyTagsToInsert;
    while (true)
    {
        //get indexes of opening tag and close tag, break, if none is found
        if((openTagPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("<sec id=\"sec", openTagPos + 1)) == -1)
            break;
        if((closeTagPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("<sec id=\"sec", openTagPos + 1)) == -1)
            break;
        //get the IDs of tags
        openTagId = invalidXml.Substring(
            openTagPos + 12,
            invalidXml.IndexOf('"', openTagPos + 12) - openTagPos - 12
        );
        closeTagId = invalidXml.Substring(
            closeTagPos + 12,
            invalidXml.IndexOf('"', closeTagPos + 12) - closeTagPos - 12
        );
        //count how many tags were already closed
        howManyClosingTagsAlready = 0;
        lastPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("</sec>", openTagPos);
        while (lastPos > -1 && lastPos < closeTagPos)
        {
            howManyClosingTagsAlready++;
            lastPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("</sec>", lastPos + 1);
        }

        howManyTagsToInsert = HowManyClosingTags(openTagId, closeTagId) - howManyClosingTagsAlready;
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyTagsToInsert; i++)
        {
            //insert closing tags
            invalidXml = invalidXml.Insert(closeTagPos, "</sec>");
        }
    }
    //now we have to close our last "unclosed" tag, in this case
    //</body> is treated as colsing tag, the logic stays the same
    openTagId = invalidXml.Substring(
        openTagPos + 12,
        invalidXml.IndexOf('"', openTagPos + 12) - openTagPos - 12
    );
    closeTagPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("</body>");
    howManyClosingTagsAlready = 0;
    lastPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("</sec>", openTagPos);
    while (lastPos > -1 && lastPos < closeTagPos)
    {
        howManyClosingTagsAlready++;
        lastPos = invalidXml.IndexOf("</sec>", lastPos + 1);
    }

    howManyTagsToInsert = openTagId.Count(ch => ch == '.') + 1 - howManyClosingTagsAlready;

    for (int i = 0; i < howManyTagsToInsert; i++)
    {
        //insert closing tags
        invalidXml = invalidXml.Insert(closeTagPos, "</sec>");
    }

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(invalidXml);
}
```

Comment: your code does not generate the </sec> tags before the </body>

Comment: @Don_B I checked the program and it does generate those tags. Does line `xml.LoadXml(invalidXml);` throw exception? If not, then all tags are closed.

Comment: `xml.LoadXml(invalidXml);` does throw exception, thats why I was using `File.WriteAllText(file, invalidXml);` instead of that, but that does not generate the </sec>'s before </body>

Comment: Are you using XML you provided or is it new document? If so, upload it, e.g. on Dropbox and give me the link, then I'll take a look.

Comment: It's a different xml document...take a look at this link https://codeshare.io/aJW41r

Comment: @Don_B Updated solution

Comment: thanks...BTW, does your code modify the file apart from just inserting </sec>'s in the file? I do not want the program to MODIFY/DELETE/CONVERT any string or tag in the file, it should just add </sec> in the file in the required position(if required)...I did go through your code and did not find any such things to my knowledge but I want to be sure...

Comment: @Don_B No, it doesn't even deal with file, once you read all text method (e.g. `File.ReadAllText()`), the connection with file ends, then it just inserts closing tags, nothing more. Then, you can save parsed XML to another file or overwite existing one.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the [Html Agility Pack nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/). It's intended to parse HTML but it can parse XML too (to some extent).
It will fix unclosed tag automatically which is cool, you don't need to parse invalid markup by yourself, no regex, etc... However, it cannot be smart enough to do so according to your document's rule.

So what we can do is use it to convert the original text to a valid Xml document and process that document using standard Xml APIs. Here is some sample code that will demonstrate this:

```
static void SafeMain(string[] args)
{
    // convert bad xml into good xml (preserving encoding)
    // html agility pack will fix unclosed node automatically
    // but it will close them at document's end, as it cannot be smart enough to fix "sec" sections depending on the attribute value
    var doc = new HtmlDocument(); // from HtmlAgilityPack namespace
    doc.Load("MyPseudoXml.txt");
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms, doc.StreamEncoding))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, doc.StreamEncoding))
            {
                xml.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    var body = xml["body"];

    // fix parenting
    // we need to process all nodes before doing final replacement
    var replaces = new List<XmlNode>();

    foreach (var node in body.SelectNodes("//sec").OfType<XmlElement>().Where(e => e.GetAttribute("id")?.IndexOf('.') < 0))
    {
        // since parenting is wrong, some nodes can again contain "root" sec nodes, so we want to remove them from this node
        // but keep them in the whole document, so we clone nodes
        var clone = node.CloneNode(true);
        foreach (var child in clone.SelectNodes("//sec").OfType<XmlElement>().Where(e => e.GetAttribute("id")?.IndexOf('.') < 0))
        {
            child.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child);
        }

        replaces.Add(clone);
    }

    // now clear body and insert back all processed nodes
    body.RemoveAll();
    foreach (var replace in replaces)
    {
        body.AppendChild(replace);
    }

    // save the valid xml file
    xml.Save("MyXml.xml");
}
```